# can jquery append an image in input part?

Tags: jquery

I want to peend an image in input part.(in the input box, after the value word) Can jquery do that? Thanks.

```
$("#click").click(function(){   
$("#text").append("<img class='loading' src='load.gif'/>");
...
});

<form name="form">
<input type="text" id="text">
<a id="click">search</a>
</form>
```

Comment: No. `input` elements have no content. And the value cannot be anything else than text. You might be able to achieve such an effect with an overlapping div...

Comment: @Felix Kling, thanks, so may be append a new div with `position:absolute`, but it is hard to put the image after `input values`. I need an effection, put the loading image after the input value typed. (one word, 2 words, the image always after these words)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to achieve this

```
$("#click").click(function(){   
$("#text").css('background', 'url(load.gif);');
...
});

<form name="form">
<input type="text" id="text">
<a id="click">search</a>
</form>
```

am I wrong?

Comment: I am sorry, I need a method add an image in input put, if can. With your method, we can use  `$("#text").after("<img class='loading' src='load.gif'/>");`, even do not need creat a span. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, try it now. (answer changed)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert image elements inside of `input type="text"` elements. You can however:

- Set the image as a background on the element
- Overlay the image on top of it (not appending it inside it) using CSS

Comment: It can be a gif even animated one.

Comment: @fish man example of animated gif background in an input element: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/yGwBu/